# Django MultiSelectField: Make some choices readonly when editing

Tags: python, django

I'm using [Django MultiSelectField](https://github.com/goinnn/django-multiselectfield) to store a project's category/categories.

My requirement is as follows: A project can have one or more categories. When creating a project initially, the user should be able to select any of the categories listed in the select field. If a user selects 'Not Applicable', then the other categories become disabled.

When editing a project, user should not be able to unselect the originally selected categorie(s), but he can add/select other categories in addition to the original ones. The originally selected categories should be readonly when editing.

My model looks like this:

```
from multiselectfield import MultiSelectField
(...)

class Project(models.Model):

    CAT_0 = 0
    CAT_1 = 1
    CAT_2 = 2
    CAT_3 = 3

    PROJECT_CATEGORIES = (
        (CAT_0, _('Not Applicable')),
        (CAT_1, _('My Category 1')),
        (CAT_2, _('My Category 2')),
        (CAT_3, _('My Category 3')),
    )
    (...)
    project_categories =  MultiSelectField(choices=PROJECT_CATEGORIES, max_choices=3, default=CAT_0)
```

And my `forms.py`

```
class ProjectForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        (...)    

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProjectForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        (...)

        if self.instance.pk:
            for choice in self.fields['project_categories'].choices:
                if str(choice[0]) in self.instance.project_categories:
                    #TODO: Make this choice to be readonly i.e. user should not be able to uncheck it
                else:
                    #TODO: Leave the choice as it is i.e. user can select/check it

            # This is what I had earlier, but it makes all the choices to be readonly. Not what I want
            self.fields['strategic_objectives'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
            self.fields['strategic_objectives'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = True
```

How do I make sure that the original categories are shown as readonly?
Is this the way to go about it or JS will be a better option?

Answer (score 0):

Is kinda useless doing that in backend before rendering, because an user can modifies your html code and enable it again.

So, disable them using JS and then in your Backend after user submit the form, you need to check it.

No metters what, have front-end validations is up to you, but you always need to have them in your backend as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you and solved it with the help of [this blogpost](https://www.abidibo.net/blog/2017/10/16/add-data-attributes-option-tags-django-admin-select-field/).
Basically it is necessary to modify the widget which is used to display the choices to be able to mark some choices as disabled.

So I created a `widgets.py` with the following content:

```py
from django.forms import CheckboxSelectMultiple


class CheckboxSelectMultipleWithDisabled(CheckboxSelectMultiple):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.disabled = kwargs.pop("disabled", set())

        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def create_option(self, *args, **kwargs):
        options_dict = super().create_option(*args, **kwargs)

        if options_dict["value"] in self.disabled:
            options_dict["attrs"]["disabled"] = True

        return options_dict
```

Then in the constructor of the form class (`ProjectForm`) I exchanged the widget of the respective field (`project_categories`) and used the added `disabled` keyword argument introduced above:

```py
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProjectForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # fill a local 'disabled' set/list/tuple/... variable using your logic

        self.fields['project_categories'].widget = CheckboxSelectMultipleWithDisabled(
            choices=self.fields['project_categories'].choices,
            disabled=disabled
        )
```

Also do not forget to import the new widget to use it: `from .widgets import CheckboxSelectMultipleWithDisabled`.

What levi posted is still true, though: you can remove the `disabled` tag in the html code in your browser and be able to modify the choice again.
So without any extra validation you have to trust your users.

A similar solution is presented in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48935945/disable-choice-in-modelmultiplechoicefield-checkboxselectmultiple-django).