# Display a checkbox choice as "disabled" in django 3.0. ModelForm

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

I've been looking around for similar issues and I've yet to come across a solution to my specific problem. What I aim to do is display a checkbox like this.

[Where only the signed in (authenticated) user has the ability to select/deselect the checkbox corresponding to his profile. In this case, mindspace is authenticated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvnLE.png)

I reached this point by trying this solution: [But as one of the comments suggest the create_option method doesn't get called through the CheckboxSelectMultiple class.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48935945/disable-choice-in-modelmultiplechoicefield-checkboxselectmultiple-django)

As a result I messed a bit with the SelectMultiple class, like-so.

```py
class CheckboxCustom(forms.SelectMultiple):


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.input_type = 'checkbox'
        self.checked_attribute = {'checked': True}
        self.template_name = 'django/forms/widgets/checkbox_select.html'
        self.option_template_name = 'django/forms/widgets/checkbox_option.html'
        self.allow_multiple_selected = True
        self.request = kwargs.pop("request")
        self.option_inherits_attrs = False
        # print(options
        super(CheckboxCustom, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


    def create_option(self, *args, **kwargs):
        options_dict = super().create_option(*args, **kwargs)
        selected = options_dict['selected']
        print(selected)
        option_attrs = self.build_attrs(self.attrs, attrs) if self.option_inherits_attrs else {}
        # if selected:
        #     options_dict['attrs']['multiple'] = True

        if options_dict['label'] != str(self.request.user.profile):
            options_dict['attrs']['disabled'] = True
            # print(val)

        return options_dict
```

And used this as a widget. However, no matter if I select or deselect one of the two checkboxes (from the corresponding profile), the other will get deselected both in the template and the database.

Same thing happens if I use the regular SelectMultiple templates and input types.

Is there a way to solve my problem?

Comment: Ok, so as with other similar issues it is an HTML "feature" and not so much a django problem. rendering a checkbox as disabled simply doesn't POST any data to the backend.

I used "onclick"="return false" and it works fine but I now have to validate the data on the server side and/or find out how to prevent manipulation of the checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked out a solution which I will post here in case anyone is interested.

As I've already mentioned, a 'disabled' attribute doesn't let any form of data to get POSTed. That means, that in a MultipleSelect field the one that is disabled, cannot be selected and the choice POSTed is the only one added in the database (disabled one is "removed").

In order to bypass this I gave a 'readonly' attribute to the field, which I later customized with CSS and made it function to my liking with a small JS script. Here is the code:

- Setting the read-only attribute (DJANGO)

```py
    def create_option(self, *args, **kwargs):

        options_dict = super().create_option(*args, **kwargs)
        selected = options_dict['selected']
        value = options_dict['value']

        #This is my own custom logic. It can be altered of course
        if options_dict['label'] != str(self.request.user.profile):
        #This is where the attribute is set!
            options_dict['attrs']['class'] = 'readonly'
```

- Customizing the readonly field in order to look gray and "disabled" (CSS)

```css
    input.readonly {
      opacity : .50;
      filter  : alpha(opacity=50); /* IE<9 */
      cursor  : default;
    }
```

- Small script to prevent field manipulation:

```js
    $('input.readonly').on('click', function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
 })
```