# How to disable a choice in django forms ChoiceField

Tags: html, django, django-forms

Here is an exemple of what I have:

forms.py

```html
class aForm(forms.Form):
   choices = [
     ('value1', 'choice1'),
     ('value2', 'choice2'),
     ('value3', 'choice3')
   ]

   dropDownList = forms.ChoiceField(
           choices=choices)
```

I want to add the attribute Disabledd to the first choice, like this:

```html
<select>
  <option selected value="value1" disabled>choice1</option>
  <option selected value="value2">choice2</option>
  <option selected value="value3">choice3</option>
</select>
```

How can I add that Disabled attribute from the forms.py file ?

Answer (score 0):

After long search I didn't find the solution am looking for, but I did pass that problem with another aproch, what I did is creating a completly RAW html form from scratch where I had full power so I added the "disabled" attribute to the first option, without touching the views.py file, what I mean is am still using forms.Form and all the validations I already writen, this works by just naming your the fields in the RAW html form the same names as in the Form.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at solution to this question. It pretty much addresses the same.

[Disable Choice In ModelMultipleChoiceField CheckBoxSelectMultiple Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48935945/disable-choice-in-modelmultiplechoicefield-checkboxselectmultiple-django)